# Data passing using props in router is not working

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to send data from one vue component to another by using props in router. but it is not working. whenever i try to log the props it outputs undefined. code is given below

**From where data is sending**

[image]

**Where receiving**

[image]

**in index.js. router setting**

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text and not images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

None of the code you've posted matches up.

Firstly, the console logging should be just `console.log(this.myprops)`. The point of using props is that you don't need to reference the router itself, e.g. via `$router`.

Next problem, you're mixing `path` and `params`. That isn't allows. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html. `params` are for named routes.

I imagine what you're aiming for is something like this:

```js
self.$router.replace({ name: 'DashboardPatient', params: { myprops: authUser.email } })
```

with router config:

```js
{
  path: '/patient',
  component: Dash,
  children: [
    {
      path: ':myprops', // <--- Adding myprops to the URL 
      name: 'DashboardPatient',
      component: DashboardPatient,
      props: true,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true }
    }
  ]
}
```

Keep in mind that routing is all about building and parsing the URL. So the value of `myprops` needs to be in the URL somewhere. In my example it comes at the end, so you'll get `/patient/user@example.com` as the URL. If it weren't in the URL then there'd be no way for the router to populate the prop if the user hit that page directly (or refreshed the page).

To hit the same route using a `path` instead of a `name` it'd be something like this:

```js
self.$router.replace({ path: `patient/${encodeURIComponent(authUser.email)}` })
```

or even just:

```js
self.$router.replace(`patient/${encodeURIComponent(authUser.email)}`)
```

Personally I'd go with the named route so that the encoding is handled automatically.

If you don't want to put the data in the URL then routing is not the appropriate way to pass it along. You'd need to use an alternative, such as putting it in the Vuex store.

Comment: your solution is helpful but i want to pass value secrately